# fabricjs - canvas downloads image twice on loadFromJSON

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In my app, i load an image on canvas from server. After clearing canvas, i load same canvas with loadFromJSON. This time, even if the image is on browser cache and url is same, it downloads image again. So, it creates a delay in my app.

```
var imageURL = <blabla>.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/image.jpg
myApp.addImageWithURL(imageURL); //This adds image on canvas so downloads it on cache.
```

Next, i clear canvas and keeps it json in localStorage.

```
myApp.canvas.clear();
myApp.loadJsonOnStorage();
```

Last part, i load json which keeps image i loaded in first step.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json); //fabric.js function
```

So, when i call this function, it starts to download the image which it keeps in cache.

Why this is happening, downloading same image with same url. Generally, it hapens in chrome private browsing, may be because of it doesnt keep any cache(i'm not sure about it) but sometimes happens in chrome normal browsing.